# CJSON::encode a javascript function

Tags: yii, json

I use jQuery widget factory (jQuery widgets) for my js widgets.

```
$.widget('cool.someWidget', {
     options: {
         onSomething: null
     }
     // other js code
});
```

Normally to run the widget from js you write

```
$(selector).someWidget({
    onSomething: function() { ..... }
});
```

In Yii I use CJSON::encode to compile all the initialization properties which include the onSomething event.

```
echo CJSON::encode(array(
    'onSomething' => 'function() {....}',
));
```

However due to the conversion (CJSON), it converts the function() {...} to a string so in the document it is written the following

```
$(selector).someWidget({
    onSomething: "function() { .... }"
});
```

because the onSomething is actually a string when I call the this._trigger('onSomething') it doesn't run the code.

This problem I have only when I "generate" the view and not with Ajax requests (which I handle differently in the system). Is there some "normal" way of making Yii actually write in the document the function withought the quotes?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScriptExpression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a build in way to prevent the encode function from wrapping function declaration with quotes , you should add **js:** before your function declaration

```
CJavaScript::enocde(array(
   'prop'=>'value',
   'callback' => 'js:function(){}'
))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the premise of the question is flawed, and it would be much better if you side-stepped this issue entirely.

What is the problem here? You cannot supply JavaScript code as a PHP string.

Why do you want to do that? I don't believe a compelling reason exists. JavaScript code should be written as JavaScript code; writing it as a string is simply worse.

It is quite probable that you wanted to pass a bunch of options available to you as PHP variables to the plugin, and in the excitement it seemed a good idea to pass *all* the options (including those that are functions) in the same manner.

But there is another way, courtesy of [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/): use `CJSON::encode` for all the scalars (strings, numbers) and switch back to pure JavaScript for the callbacks.

```
$(selector).someWidget($.extend(
    <?php echo CJSON::encode(array(/* no functions here, just scalars */));?>,
    { // and now, back in JavaScript-land, code follows:
        onSomething: function() { ..... }
    }
));
```

Comment: It feels fare to be able to do that. Yii has the CJSON so it correctly encodes all strings to strings. But sometimes all you need to do "bind" plugins in a chain is to run a function of a plugin on the event of another. As to why I want to do that in PHP (Yii)? So my widgets can correctly write everything and not suffer from the overhead of selecting and binding.

Comment: This should be the answer, imho

Comment: @Jon: We're talking about widgets here. Reusable pieces of code, Yii developers can insert into their applications. How would you like to pass Javascript code in this case? As you can see, _a compelling reason **does** exist_. And, now what? You throw you hat in, and when defeated with a good quality argument, you're not even willing to respond? How polite...

Comment: @trejder: The astute reader will notice that while *jQuery* widgets are specifically referenced in the question, *Yii* widgets are not. There's a reference to Yii of course but *nothing in the question talks about Yii widgets*. There is even *nothing in the comment above referring to Yii widgets*. There's also nothing like that in the OP's "final solution" below. So before going around accusing people, perhaps checking your assumptions would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function which does exactly what I wanted. Still if there's some native Yii solution I'd really love to know it.

```
public function encodeOpts($data, $jsCode = null) {
    $rVal = CJSON::encode($data);

    if ($jsCode == null)
        return $rVal;

    foreach($jsCode as $key => $code) {
        $codeEntries[] = "\"{$key}\": {$code}";
    }

    return substr_replace($rVal, ', ' . implode(', ', $codeEntries), -1) . '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
if ($this->user_options !== null && is_array($this->user_options))
{
    $reqs = CJavaScript::encode(
        array_merge(
            $this->user_options,
            array(
                // adding a default callback to options 
                'onLoad' => 'js: function() {$("#info").text("Hi")}'
                )
            )
        );
}
```

NOTE: `js:` only works for `CJavaScript` not for`CJSON`